# ERROR running force:package:version:create An object 'My Profine' of type Profile was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Hi all after updated `sfdx` to version `7.72.0` when I try to create the unlocked package - it fails with the error:

`ERROR running force:package:version:create:  An error occurred while trying to install a package dependency, ID 04t3u000002znQE: Admin: An object 'Admin' of type Profile was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory.`

NOTE: It was working without any problems with version `7.71.0`

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem, I ran `sfdx update` and it bumped to 7.73 and my error went away. Salesforce must have just fixed the bug.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me as well after the `sfdx` update.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue like you.
To resolve that wse the latest version: 7.73.2-feef087df8 of sfdx with the command sfdx update.
It works